# Adding components to CoverFlow in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, coverflow

I'm working with the [CoverFlow library by Doug McCune](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/11/03/coverflow-flex-component/).

In the example included, he has created some panels inside a `CoverFlowContainer`. There are other examples of him populating the coverflow from an RSS feed on the page linked above but he doesn't include the source for these :(

I will eventually be retrieving data from a web service to add to the coverflow however I'm starting with this simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"    xmlns:containers="com.dougmccune.containers.*" creationComplete="init()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.controls.TextArea;

        public var articlePanel:Panel = new Panel();
        public var articleTextArea:TextArea = new TextArea();

        private function init() : void
        {
            articlePanel.addChild(articleTextArea);
            articlePanel.title = "test tile"
            articleTextArea.text = "article1" + "\n" + "www.article.com" + "\n" + "hello this is article 1";
            coverflow2.addChild(articlePanel);  
        }       
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox id="box" verticalGap="0" height="306" width="100%" maxWidth="600" maxHeight="300" >

           <containers:CoverFlowContainer id="coverflow2" width="100%" height="244" 
            horizontalGap="40" borderStyle="inset" backgroundColor="0x000000"
            segments="6" reflectionEnabled="true">

            <mx:Panel id="testpanel" width="200" height="200" title="Mxml title">
                <mx:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%">
                    <mx:columns>
                        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 1" dataField="col1"/>
                        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 2" dataField="col2"/>
                        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Column 3" dataField="col3"/>
                    </mx:columns>
                </mx:DataGrid>
            </mx:Panel>

            <mx:Panel id="buttonpanel" width="200" height="200" title="Mxml title">
                <mx:Button id="myButton" label="Change title" click="buttonpanel.title = ('hello') "/>
            </mx:Panel>
        </containers:CoverFlowContainer>                
    </mx:VBox>
     </mx:Application>
```

I've defined some panels in the mxml and set `creationComplete=init()` so that the new panel I've created in ActionScript will be added to the CoverFlow container.

When I launch the application it displays the two predefined panels but not the one I have created in ActionScript.

Any ideas? Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by first defining the coverflow container with nothing in it:

```
<containers:CoverFlowContainer id="coverflow" width="100%" height="244" 
                horizontalGap="40" borderStyle="inset" backgroundColor="0x000000"
                reflectionEnabled="true"/>
```

In the actionscript section I retrieve an array from a web service and for each item in the array I create a panel. It is important to give each panel a width and height otherwise it will only show one element in the coverflow or no elements at all:

```
articlePanel.width = 200;
articlePanel.height = 200;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try mx:Repeater component

```
<mx:HTTPService id="srv" url="pics.xml"/>
<ns2:CarouselContainer id="cf" width="100%" height="303" horizontalGap="40"
                       segments="6" reflectionEnabled="true" angle="10" >

    <mx:Repeater id="r" dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.images.image}">
        <mx:Canvas width="200" height="200">
            <mx:Image source="{r.currentItem.src}"/>
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:Repeater>

</ns2:CarouselContainer>
```